# Xcode multiple target only add file once

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a iOS project with multiple targets. Each target has its own plist but builds the same code base to produce slightly different versions of the app.

This works fine but there are some minor issues.

Whenever I add a file (code file/resource), I have to remember to add to all targets.
When I resolve conflicts between branches, it is much more tedious since there are many conflicts in the project.pbxproj file since each codefile/resource is duplicated multiple times.

Is there a way such that I only add to 1 target and make the rest of the targets "inherit" from it. I looked at target dependencies but it doesn't seem to achieve what I want.

Comment: When you add a file, first time you need to check all targets, after that each time you add a new file XCode remembers and automatically shows your previous selection. (It keeps the same selection until you change it to another, so I don't think it's a tedious process).

Comment: Yes but we have several people working on the same project and it would be easy to miss out something like a image file as it would just compile just fine. And we still have the messy conflict issue.